# Closing Result is not correct in acounts opening and Closing Balance in SQL Query?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I and finding daily accounts opening and closing Balance but it gives me wrong result when there are more than a record on same date. here is my query

```
    SELECT cast(TransDate as date)
, SUM ([Total deposits]) As 'Total deposits'
, SUM ([Total withdrawals]) As 'Total withdrawals'
, SUM (ClosingBalance) AS ClosingBalance
FROM (
SELECT TransDate
, ISNULL (SUM (Ledger.Cr), 0) AS 'Total deposits'
, ISNULL (SUM (Ledger.Dr), 0) AS 'Total withdrawals'
, 0 AS ClosingBalance
FROM Ledger where Ledger.TransDate between '2014-02-14' and '2014-02-20'
GROUP BY Ledger.TransDate 
UNION ALL

SELECT TransDate
, 0 AS 'Total deposits'
, 0 AS 'Total withdrawals'
, ISNULL ((SELECT SUM (MT2.Cr) FROM Ledger MT2 WHERE MT2.TransDate  <= MT.TransDate), 0)
- ISNULL ((SELECT SUM (MT2.Dr) FROM Ledger MT2 WHERE cast(MT2.TransDate as date ) <= MT.TransDate), 0)

FROM Ledger MT where TransDate between '2014-02-14' and '2014-02-20'
GROUP BY Transdate
) AS X
GROUP BY cast(TRANSDATE as date)
```

result of query

[image]

here is my db file script

```
USE [MDS]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Ledger]    Script Date: 03/26/2014 23:42:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ledger](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PrisonerID] [int] NULL,
    [TransDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Dr] [money] NULL,
    [Cr] [money] NULL,
    [Partical] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Ledger] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Ledger] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Ledger] ([id], [PrisonerID], [TransDate], [Dr], [Cr], [Partical]) VALUES (1, 5, CAST(0x0000A2D200D9255B AS DateTime), 0.0000, 500.0000, N'payment recived')
INSERT [dbo].[Ledger] ([id], [PrisonerID], [TransDate], [Dr], [Cr], [Partical]) VALUES (2, 5, CAST(0x0000A2D300D9255B AS DateTime), 0.0000, 200.0000, N'withdraw')
INSERT [dbo].[Ledger] ([id], [PrisonerID], [TransDate], [Dr], [Cr], [Partical]) VALUES (3, 5, CAST(0x0000A2D400DBE47B AS DateTime), 20.0000, 0.0000, N'withdraw')
INSERT [dbo].[Ledger] ([id], [PrisonerID], [TransDate], [Dr], [Cr], [Partical]) VALUES (4, 5, CAST(0x0000A2D200000000 AS DateTime), 10.0000, 0.0000, N'withdraw')
INSERT [dbo].[Ledger] ([id], [PrisonerID], [TransDate], [Dr], [Cr], [Partical]) VALUES (5, 5, CAST(0x0000A2D700D9255B AS DateTime), 0.0000, 200.0000, N'payment revived')
INSERT [dbo].[Ledger] ([id], [PrisonerID], [TransDate], [Dr], [Cr], [Partical]) VALUES (6, 5, CAST(0x0000A2D20083D600 AS DateTime), 10.0000, 0.0000, N'withdraw')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Ledger] OFF
/****** Object:  Default [DF_Ledger_Dr]    Script Date: 03/26/2014 23:42:04 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ledger] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Ledger_Dr]  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [Dr]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_Ledger_Cr]    Script Date: 03/26/2014 23:42:04 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ledger] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Ledger_Cr]  DEFAULT ((0.0000)) FOR [Cr]
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple problems conspiring against you. First, you're `summing` and `grouping` on dates, but you're leaving the timestamps intact. Then, your `UNION ALL` is causing those to duplicate in your calculations. If you had other deposits on the same dates, you'd see those numbers inflate as well.

You can also combine your summation query into one `SELECT` with some correlated subqueries, like so:

```
SELECT dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, a.TransDate), 0)
, ISNULL (SUM (a.Cr), 0) AS 'Total deposits'
, ISNULL (SUM (a.Dr), 0) AS 'Total withdrawals'
, ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Cr) from Ledger where dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, TransDate), 0) <= dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, a.TransDate), 0)), 0)
- ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Dr) from Ledger where dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, TransDate), 0) <= dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, a.TransDate), 0)), 0) as 'Closing Balance'
FROM Ledger a
where a.TransDate between '2014-02-14' and '2014-02-20'
GROUP BY dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, a.TransDate), 0)
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f87ba/20) to demonstrate.

Further, you'd probably also want to group on `PrisonerID` or you'll get the same results for every prisoner.

Comment: no i don't need to do any thing with PrisonerID i just need the result like shown in picture but not getting what problem with query